# how to verify both password and confirm password are equal?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am using laravel 5.2. My page contains fields password and confirm password. I want to check whether the password and confirm password are equal. The below given is my view page part. Also i want to know how to validate password and confirm password?

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Password</label>
        <div class="col-md-6"> 
            <input type="password" class="form-control"   placeholder="Enter Your Password" name="password" id="password" data-parsley-trigger="change" data-parsley-required="true" data-parsley-equalto="#password" data-parsley-minlength="6" data-parsley-maxlength="14" required>
            {!! $errors->first('password', '<label class="control-label" for="password">:message</label>')!!}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Confirm Password</label>
        <div class="col-md-6"> 
            <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Please Confirm Your Password" name="password_confirmation" id="password_confirmation" data-parsley-trigger="change" data-parsley-required="true" data-parsley-equalto="#password" data-parsley-minlength="6" data-parsley-maxlength="14" required>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`confirmed`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#rule-confirmed) validation rule:

```
'password' => 'required|confirmed',
```

That's how Laravel does this in `validator()` method during new user registration.

Answer (score 0):

Please just do small change in your validation rules,
Plz refer following example:

```
  public static $rules = [   
       'password' => 'required|min:3|confirmed',
       'password_confirmation' => 'required|min:3'   
    ];
```

Answer (score 0):

Code :

< input type="password" name="password" id="password" required>

< input type="password" name="password" id="confirm_password" required>

And for the validation part. Just use the "**confirmed**" validation rules

'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed

See this - [enter link description here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#rule-confirmed)